# get groups id more than one and get nothing results

Tags: python, odoo

I was trying to give a condition for a group and directly for 2 group and of course I got two group ids. After getting the group ids I would like to execute the following code, but the result is blank. Here goes the code:

```
new_data = []    
check_groups = self.env['res.groups'].search([('name', 'in', ['groups_A', 'groups_B')])
for news in check_groups:
   new_data.append(news.id)
self.groups_id= ([4, new_data])
```

I got two group ids and I did not get an error, just didn't get the result.

But, if I use just one groups like :

```
check_groups = self.env['res.groups'].search([('name', '=', 'groups_A')])
```

It works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to this:

```py
 for news in check_groups:
   new_data.append((4,news.id))
self.groups_id= new_data
```

relation field accept list of cammand:

```
[(command_code, value, value), ....]
```

Comment: You are my saveor, it's working. Thank you so much!! @Tchi-Odoo

Comment: Lol love it, Thank you too